# (php) fwrite erase and doesn't write

Tags: php, fwrite

I have a file "tw.txt" with the text "test text" in it.

If I try to write "lol" in "tx.txt" with `fwrite`, the content ("test text") is simply erased and not replaced.

There is no error displayed by the server, however, I can see my `Error: can't write in file.`

`CHMOD` is set to 777 in every files and folders, from the "var" rep to the website folder. If I try to read a file with `fopen`, no problem. I tried to change the `chmod` with PHP... no success. I tried to append, it erase.

The code works fine on two other servers.

Any clues ? Thanks.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');    
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$fd=fopen("tw.txt","w") or die("Error: can't open file.");  
//chmod("tw.txt", 511);     
fwrite($fd,"lol") or die('Error: can't write in file.');
fclose($fd); 
?>
```

Comment: Have you failed to close the file? What is the OS of the dev server? Is it windoze, per chance? Also, why allow_url_fopen?

Comment: You can find at manual function [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php). It's second param is mode. You can check **A list of possible modes** and find out what you need. Also you can use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) with flag **FILE_APPEND**.

Comment: Thanks Hood for your anwser. Have you failed to close the file?=>It's the actuel piece of code, I didn't open the file before. It's linux (dev folder, etc, home). url_fopen is something I tried (fwrite, "http://..").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                     $myFile = 'tw.txt';
                     $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
                     fwrite($fh, 'lol');
                     fclose($fh);
```

Comment: I left a couple of hours my computer, then when I came back, I tried your code: it works. Out of curiosity, I tested my old test code and my main code again: they also worked. Maybe the server have a kind of latency before changing chmod? That's weird. Thanks for your answer anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried other opening modes?

If you need to append some data, you should try something like:

```
$fd=fopen("tw.txt","a+")
```